# How to real-time convert the PCM buffer to AAC data when recording for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I'm using Remote.IO to get the audio buffer from PCM, but the raw data is too big to send to remote-side by cellular network (3G network). I did reference some articles, but most of them suggest converting **file** to the other format file.

Is there any way to convert the audio buffer to AAC encoding data in **real-time**?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed save the audio buffer directly into AAC format.

While setting the ASBD, set it like this

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
```

Specify `kAudioFileM4AType` while calling ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL like this:

```
err = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)audioFileURL,
                             kAudioFileM4AType,
                             &audioFormat, 
                             NULL,
                             kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                             &outFile);
```

You also need to set the codec like this.

```
UInt32 codecManf = kAppleSoftwareAudioCodecManufacturer;
ExtAudioFileSetProperty(outFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_CodecManufacturer, sizeof(UInt32), &codecManf);
```

This should help you get your AAC encoding working.

Comment: I think this is not the solution which I expected.
whatever I just resovled this problem, I using iLBC encoding and Audio Convert Service.

Comment: @PatrickSCLin, did you do the conversion using an AudioConvert audio unit with `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer`?

Comment: Hi, do you have any example that show how to use iLBC encoding and Audio Convert service?